# how to put sage pay by ebizmarts into test mode using magento community edition

Tags: magento, opayo, magento-1.8

I was wondering does anybody know how to put sage pay by ebizmarts into test mode, using magento community edition would I need to edit some code or is there a way within the configuration settings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's not a setting in the magento extension, you can set it on you're sagepay account. Do you have an account where you can try to login to look for same setting?

Comment: noo I currently don't have a sage pay account but I can make one if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the answer is really, simple, each integration, Server, Server MOTO, Direct, Direct Moto, etc. have their own **Mode** setting, if you change this, the transaction will be posted in the chosen mode.

Please see this image as an example:
[image]

Kind Regards,

Pablo

Comment: ok thank you that is awesome this is what i needed i just know need to make a sage pay account to test this is or is there a way to test sage pay without having to create an account.

Comment: for the TEST account you need a LIVE one, so I think that if you dont have it, create a SIMULATOR account then.